# Any way to "factor out" common fields to save space?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, memory, data-structures

I have a large array (> millions) of `Item`s, where each `Item` has the form:

```
struct Item { void *a; size_t b; };
```

There are a handful of distinct `a` fields—meaning there are *many* items with the same `a` field.

I would like to "factor" this information out to save about 50% memory usage.

However, the trouble is that these `Item`s have a significant *ordering*, and that may change over time. Therefore, I can't just go ahead make a separate `Item[]` for each distinct `a`, because that will lose the relative ordering of the items with respect to each other.

On the other hand, if I *store* the orderings of all the items in a `size_t index;` field, then I lose any memory savings from the removal of the `void *a;` field.

So is there a way for me to actually save memory here, or no?

(Note: I can already think of e.g. using an `unsigned char` for `a` to index into a small array, but I'm wondering if there's a better way. That one will require me to either use unaligned memory or to split every `Item[]` into two, which isn't great for memory locality, so I'd prefer something else.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> (Note: I can already think of e.g. using an unsigned char for a to index into a small array, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.)

This thinking is on the right track, but it's not that simple, since you will run into some nasty alignment/padding issues that will negate your memory gains.

At that point, when you start trying to scratch the last few bytes of a structure like this, you will probably want to use bit fields.

```
#define A_INDEX_BITS 3
struct Item { 
  size_t a_index : A_INDEX_BITS; 
  size_t b       : (sizeof(size_t) * CHAR_BIT) - A_INDEX_BITS; 
};
```

Note that this will limit how many bits are available for `b`, but on modern platforms, where `sizeof(size_t)` is 8, stripping 3-4 bits from it is rarely an issue.

Comment: Use `CHAR_BIT` instead of 8 for maximum portability.

Comment: I see, so only handle 64-bit? Nothing I can do for 32-bit? (+1)

Comment: @einpoklum `CHAR_BIT` is the number of bits in a `char` and is thus platform-dependent. Yes, on most modern HW, it's practically guaranteed to be 8, but that need not be the case in general. Plus, `CHAR_BIT` is a bit more self-documenting than `8`.

Comment: I'm accepting this since it really does seem like the savings on 64-bit is the best I can hope for, but if someone finds a better way feel free to post. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use a combination of **lightweight compression schemes** (see [this](http://openproceedings.org/2017/conf/edbt/paper-146.pdf) for examples and some references) to represent the `a*` values. @Frank's answer employes DICT followed by NS, for example. If you have long runs of the same pointer, you could consider RLE (Run-Length Encoding) on top of that.

Comment: @skeller: If you want to get a bit more meta and philosophical about the composition of these schemes, you might be interested in a 2-page [mini-paper of mine](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324521705_Decomposing_and_re-composing_lightweight_compression_schemes_-_and_why_it_matters) as well.

Comment: +1 Sounds like this is only for 64-bit systems right? On 32-bit I wouldn't save anything? (Except for half the `void*` by nature of 32-bit which you could say is already something.)

Comment: @Mehrdad: The link was about specific implementations, but the concept is not specific to any particular hardware. After all, Frank's answer is a specific case of the general advice.

Comment: @einpoklum: Well the pointer-packing thing is specific to 64-bit -- on 32-bit I wouldn't have enough bits to lose. That's why I'm wondering if I could do better.

Comment: @Mehrdad: After applying DICT, it's only log(number of distinct `a`'s) bits.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of a hack, but I've used it in the past with some success. The extra overhead for object access was compensated for by the significant memory reduction.

A typical use case is an environment where (a) values are actually discriminated unions (that is, they include a type indicator) with a limited number of different types and (b) values are mostly kept in large contiguous vectors.

With that environment, it is quite likely that the payload part of (some kinds of) values uses up all the bits allocated for it. It is also possible that the datatype requires (or benefits from) being stored in aligned memory.

In practice, now that aligned access is not required by most mainstream CPUs, I would just used a packed struct instead of the following hack. If you don't pay for unaligned access, then storing a { one-byte type + eight-byte value } as nine contiguous bytes is probably optimal; the only cost is that you need to multiply by 9 instead of 8 for indexed access, and that is trivial since the 9 is a compile-time constant.

If you do have to pay for unaligned access, then the following is possible. Vectors of "augmented" values have the type:

```
// Assume that Payload has already been typedef'd. In my application,
// it would be a union of, eg., uint64_t, int64_t, double, pointer, etc.
// In your application, it would be b.

// Eight-byte payload version:
typedef struct Chunk8 { uint8_t kind[8]; Payload value[8]; }

// Four-byte payload version:
typedef struct Chunk4 { uint8_t kind[4]; Payload value[4]; }
```

Vectors are then vectors of Chunks. For the hack to work, they must be allocated on 8- (or 4-)byte aligned memory addresses, but we've already assumed that alignment is required for the Payload types.

The key to the hack is how we represent a pointer to an individual value, because the value is not contiguous in memory. We use a pointer to it's `kind` member as a proxy:

```
typedef uint8_t ValuePointer;
```

And then use the following low-but-not-zero-overhead functions:

```
#define P_SIZE 8U
#define P_MASK P_SIZE - 1U
// Internal function used to get the low-order bits of a ValuePointer.
static inline size_t vpMask(ValuePointer vp) {
  return (uintptr_t)vp & P_MASK;
}
// Getters / setters. This version returns the address so it can be
// used both as a getter and a setter
static inline uint8_t* kindOf(ValuePointer vp) { return vp; }
static inline Payload* valueOf(ValuePointer vp) {
  return (Payload*)(vp + 1 + (vpMask(vp) + 1) * (P_SIZE - 1));
}

// Increment / Decrement
static inline ValuePointer inc(ValuePointer vp) {
  return vpMask(++vp) ? vp : vp + P_SIZE * P_SIZE;
}

static inline ValuePointer dec(ValuePointer vp) {
  return vpMask(vp--) ? vp - P_SIZE * P_SIZE : vp;
}

// Simple indexed access from a Chunk pointer
static inline ValuePointer eltk(Chunk* ch, size_t k) {
  return &ch[k / P_SIZE].kind[k % P_SIZE];
}

// Increment a value pointer by an arbitrary (non-negative) amount
static inline ValuePointer inck(ValuePointer vp, size_t k) {
  size_t off = vpMask(vp);
  return eltk((Chunk*)(vp - off), k + off);
}
```

I left out a bunch of the other hacks but I'm sure you can figure them out.

One cool thing about interleaving the pieces of the value is that it has moderately good locality of reference. For the 8-byte version, almost half of the time a random access to a kind and a value will only hit one 64-byte cacheline; the rest of the time two consecutive cachelines are hit, with the result that walking forwards (or backwards) through a vector is just as cache-friendly as walking through an ordinary vector, except that it uses fewer cachelines because the objects are half the size. The four byte version is even cache-friendlier.

Comment: Sounds pretty similar to my answer if I'm understanding correctly :) +1

Comment: @Mehrdad: If it is, I didn't understand your answer. It's more like "Array of Structures" except that the arrays are interleaved, or the "Packed structures" (currently accepted answer) except that the packing is permuted. Unlike what you say about yours, it doesn't require unaligned memory access and it lets you easily add new values of a (until you run into the limit of a unit8_t, so maybe that's not different). The vectors aren't dynamically shaped -- at least, they weren't in my application -- and only bit operations are used in indexing.

Comment: The hack here is the way I use a single pointer to represent a non-contiguous struct. I'm not saying that I'm the first person to think of this, but perhaps I'm the first person not to embarrassed by the hack to admit it :) I used it years ago in a POC for an interpreter VM, on a CPU which didn't like misaligned floats and which didn't have excess RAM.

Comment: Ah yeah -- in my case I was encoding the bits of `a` and `b` into a single integer (to get it closer to the info-theoretic optimum) but in your case you're keeping them separate for faster performance. Seems like we spanned the entire spectrum in all the answers here. :-)

Comment: Also, this one does work on 32-bit payloads. But so does just going with unaligned structs, unless your architecture prohibits it.

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured out the information-theoretically-optimal way to do this myself... it's not quite worth the gains in my case, but I'll explain it here in case it helps someone else.
However, it requires unaligned memory (in some sense).
And perhaps more importantly, you lose the ability easily add new values of `a` dynamically.

What really matters here is the number of distinct `Item`s, i.e. the number of distinct `(a,b)` pairs. After all, it could be that for one `a` there are a billion different `b`s, but for the other ones there are only a handful, so you want to take advantage of that.

If we assume that there are `N` distinct items to choose from, then we need `n = ceil(log2(N))` bits to represent each `Item`. So what we really want is an array of `n`-bit integers, with `n` computed at *run time*. Then, once you get the `n`-bit integer, you can do a binary search in `log(n)` time to figure out which `a` it corresponds to, based on your knowledge of the count of `b`s for each `a`. (This may be a bit of a performance hit, but it depends on the number of distinct `a`s.)

You can't do this in a nice memory-aligned fashion, but that isn't too bad. What you would do is make a `uint_vector` data structure with the *number of bits per element* being a dynamically-specifiable quantity. Then, to randomly access into it, you'd do a few divisions or mod operations along with bit-shifts to extract the required integer.

The caveat here is that the dividing by a variable will probably severely damage your random-access performance (although it'll still be O(1)). The way to mitigate that would probably be to write a few different procedures for common values of `n` (C++ templates help here!) and then branch into them with various `if (n == 33) { handle_case<33>(i); }` or `switch (n) { case 33: handle_case<33>(i); }`, etc. so that the compiler sees the divisor as a constant and generates shifts/adds/multiplies as needed, rather than division.

This is information-theoretically optimal as long as you require a constant number of bits per element, which is what you would want for random-accessing. However, you could do better if you relax that constraint: you could pack *multiple* integers into `k * n` bits, then extract them with more math. This will probably kill performance too.

*(Or, long story short: C and C++ really need a high-performance `uint_vector` data structure...)*

Answer (score 2):

An Array-of-Structures approach may be helpful. That is, have three vectors...

```
vector<A> vec_a;
vector<B> vec_b;
SomeType  b_to_a_map;
```

You access your data as...

```
Item Get(int index)
{
    Item retval;
    retval.a = vec_a[b_to_a_map[index]];
    retval.b = vec_b[index];
    return retval;
}
```

Now all you need to do is choose something sensible for SomeType. For example, if vec_a.size() were 2, you could use vector<bool> or boost::dynamic_bitset. For more complex cases you could try bit-packing, for example to support 4-values of A, we simple change our function with...

```
int a_index = b_to_a_map[index*2]*2 + b_to_a_map[index*2+1];
retval.a = vec_a[a_index];
```

You can always beat bit-packing by using range-packing, using div/mod to store a fractional bit length per item, but the complexity grows quickly.

A good guide can be found here http://number-none.com/product/Packing%20Integers/index.html